# OutputStream won't save all updates on a file

Tags: java, file, header, apache-poi, fileoutputstream

I'm working on a Microsoft word 2007 Document.

my Objectives are to fill :

1. Table cell.
2. A Paragraph line.

so,my code does this work but the problem is when i write the file using FileOutputStream, it writes only one of my objectives (the last modification only).

here is an Image of the Header :

[image]

and here is  the code i used :

```
    try{

InputStream input = new FileInputStream("c:\\doslot.docx");
XWPFDocument document=new XWPFDocument(input);
 //*********************inserting the 2nd line**************************
  XWPFHeader head = document.getHeaderList().get(0);
    List<XWPFParagraph> para= head.getParagraphs();
    XWPFRun pararun=para.get(0).createRun();
    pararun.setText("DOSSIER DE LOT GLUSCAN® N°FG-4040400A");
 //*********************inserting the header thrid table cell*************************
   XWPFHeader headd = document.getHeaderList().get(1);
    List<XWPFTable> tables = headd.getTables();
    List<XWPFTableRow> rows = tables.get(0).getRows();
  XWPFTableCell cell =    rows.get(0).getTableCell(rows.get(0).getTableCells().get(3).getCTTc());
    XWPFParagraph p =cell.addParagraph();
    XWPFRun pararuno=p.createRun();
    pararuno.setText("some text");


    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("c:\\fin.docx");
    document.write(out);
    out.close();


     }catch(Exception ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `List<XWPFTableCell> cell = rows.get(0).getTableCells();` returns newly created list, [XWPFTableRow.getTableCells()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableRow.html#getTableCells%28%29) says:

> create and return a list of all XWPFTableCell who belongs to this row

And ofcourse comments do lie, while code does not, so [sources](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/3.7/poi-ooxml-3.7-sources.jar!/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableRow.java?format=ok) say:

```
public List<XWPFTableCell> getTableCells(){
    if(tableCells == null){
        //Here it is created
        List<XWPFTableCell> cells = new ArrayList<XWPFTableCell>();
        for (CTTc tableCell : ctRow.getTcList()) {
            cells.add(new XWPFTableCell(tableCell, this, table.getPart()));
        }
        this.tableCells = cells;
    }
    return tableCells;
}
```

And for your help there is a [XWPFTableRow.getTableCell(CTTc cell)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableRow.html#getTableCell%28org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTc%29), where you pass `CTTc` cell, and method definitely returns an existing object:

```
public XWPFTableCell getTableCell(CTTc cell) {
    for(int i=0; i<tableCells.size(); i++){
        if(tableCells.get(i).getCTTc() == cell) return tableCells.get(i); 
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can achieve CTTc cell by invoking [XWPFTableCell.getCTTc()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html#getCTTc%28%29) and then modify it directly.

The code to directly access existing cell would be:

```
XWPFTableCell cell = 
    rows.getTableCell(rows.get(0).getTableCells().get(3).getCTTc());
```

I did not try or compile this code, so I am not sure if it is correct, but I trust my OO knowledge and sources. By all means this should do it. If it does - please correct the code to make sure it is correct and compilable.

FTR, I think that there should be more convenient way doing this, it is quite common to edit the cells and I think it should not be so complicated, I would suggest trying some tutorials on XWPFTable and its manipulation.

Comment: Thank you, let me check this out, i was disparately waiting for an answer.

Comment: too bad it didn't work , the code is compiled with no errors, but it is still  the same thing, only one change is saved, what a bizarre thing :s

Comment: Try making the simplest example possible which only references the problem, this will help you tracking down the roots of the issue.

Comment: Well, it is always best practice to have some separate project which has simple structure and serves as a guinea pig, mainly used for simple scenarios when the problem is really fishy. Happy to help, cheers :)